# Curved text (+animation)

Tags: html, jquery, css, curve

I'm trying to have a banner in the corner of my website with curved and animated (infinite banner style) text inside a responsive div.

Something like this:
[image]

I'm a rookie at programming and also tried doing it with .svg's based on other's examples, but with little luck.

The original curve in photoshop is an "Arc upper" (+47%)

Any help much appreciated!
A

Comment: I suggest actually posting your attempts at accomplishing it. Otherwise your question will probably get closed.

Comment: Hi, my attempts were really far of, not sure if worth posting.

Like I managed to get the text on a perfect half curve, but it was nothing sort of elegant or simple

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want or not, but hope it works:

```js
function curvedText(time) {
        var tl = new TimelineMax({ repeat: -1 });
        var text = document.querySelector("svg textpath"),
          path = document.querySelector("svg defs path");

        var from = {
          transformOrigin: "center center",
          rotation: 0,
        };

        var to = {
          rotation: -360,
          ease: Linear.easeInOut,
        };

        tl.fromTo([text, path], time, from, to);

        return tl;
      }

      curvedText(20);
```

```css
body {
        position: relative;
      }
      div {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        /* border: 1px solid black; */
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      svg:not(:root) {
        overflow: visible;
      }

      svg {
        position: absolute;
        right: 50px;
        bottom: 50px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.14.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="150 -400 600 600">
      <defs>
        <path
          id="txt-path"
          d="M50, 800a800, 800 0 1, 1 1600, 0a800, 800 0 1, 1 -1600, 0"></path>
      </defs>

      <text
        fill="red"
        font-size="70px"
        font-family="Helvetica Neue"
        font-weight="600">
        <textPath startOffset="1000" xlink:href="#txt-path">
          I'm trying to have a banner in the corner of my website with curved
          and animated (infinite banner style) text inside a responsive div.
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Don't forget to add `CDN` to your codes:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.14.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```